# Function call isn't executed in verilog

Tags: verilog, function

Why function call to `clogb2` is not being executed in the following code. I don't get any compilation errors but still parameter `adder_width` is not updated with the value from `clogb2`. In fact, that function doesn't return any value.

See http://www.edaplayground.com/x/Pxc.

```verilog
module ram_model ();

   parameter ram_depth = 8;
   localparam adder_width = clogb2(ram_depth);
   initial begin
      $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
      $dumpvars(1);
      $monitor("%d",adder_width);
   end

   function integer clogb2;
      input depth;
      integer i,result;
      begin
         for (i = 0; 2**(i) < depth; i = i + 1)
            result = i + 1;
         clogb2 = result;
      end
   endfunction 

endmodule
```

Comment: It might help if you added some details about the actual system / OS / Language you are using ?

Comment: You really couldn't come up with anything more relevant than [tag:function]?

Comment: I don't know verilog, but it looks like you don't need that function clogb2. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5602167/1544337

Comment: @CeesMeijer Verilog is the language I'm using.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I was reading up on constant functions and tasks in verilog and that is how I came up with this code.

Comment: @CamilStaps I was reading up on constant functions and tasks in verilog and that is how I came up with this code

Comment: Well, yeah, of course you can write your own code to calculate the 'rounded-down 2-base log of an input plus one'. But you can also use the built-in function, which would be easier. However, it's just a side note, as I said, I don't know verilog, so I don't know what's the problem with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is called but it returns 'x' because your `depth` argument is only one bit wide and the LSB of 8 is zero, so `result` is never assigned a value.

Change the line

```
input depth;
```

to

```
input integer depth;
```

and `adder_width` will be set to 3 as expected.